# Create dummy Variables based on 2 factors and paste in a new dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dummy-variable

I send all the data so you can reproduce it yourself

```
example2<- as.data.frame(c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "G", "G", "E", "E", "F"))
example3<- as.data.frame(c("1", "2", "1", "5", "4", "1", "2", "3", "1", "4")) 
example4<-data.frame(example2,example3)
names(example4)<-c("NIT","Esp")
example4

    NIT Esp
1    A   1
2    A   2
3    B   1
4    B   5
5    B   4
6    G   1
7    G   2
8    E   3
9    E   1
10   F   4
```

I have this 10 x 2 matrix. Both NIT and Esp are factor variables.

Each letter is a subject and each number is an characteristic of a particular subject.
For example: Subject A has characteristics 1 and 2 and subject B has characteristics 1,5, 4,

I would like to create a dummy variable for each one of the characteristics 1,2,3,4,5 . If A has characteristic 2, then it produces 1 and if not it produces 0.

I tried this solution

```
for(level in unique(example4$Esp)){
  example4[paste("dummy", level, sep = "_")] <- ifelse(example4$Esp == level, 1, 0)
}
```

Sor far this what I've managed

```
    NIT Esp dummy_1 dummy_2 dummy_5 dummy_4 dummy_3
1    A   1       1       0       0       0       0
2    A   2       0       1       0       0       0
3    B   1       1       0       0       0       0
4    B   5       0       0       1       0       0
5    B   4       0       0       0       1       0
6    G   1       1       0       0       0       0
7    G   2       0       1       0       0       0
8    E   3       0       0       0       0       1
9    E   1       1       0       0       0       0
10   F   4       0       0       0       1       0
```

Nevertheless this is the matrix I really want.

The final Matrix should have 6 rows x 5 columns, It should look like this

```
NIT Esp1 Esp2 Esp3 Esp4 Esp5
 A   1    1    0    0    0
 B   1    0    0    1    1
 G   1    1    0    0    0
 E   1    0    1    0    0
 F   0    0    0    1    0
```

Comment: Just `table(example4)` I guess. Or `as.data.frame.matrix(table(example4))` for more convenient format

Comment: The melt function reshape2 package may be of use.